# How to load style from resource

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am facing a problem when I try to load a resource style from file to a UIElement.
My Resource file contains a copy of ToggleSwitch's default style, I changed just some colors.
I tried the following Resource references:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="GreenToggleResourceDictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GreenToggleSwitch.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

And my ToggleSwitch looks like this but it won't use the style in the referenced resource "GreenToggleSwitch.xaml":

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleSwitch"
      Style="{StaticResource GreenToggleSwitchStyle}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"
</ToggleSwitch>
```

This is the GreenToggleSwitch.xaml, it's pretty much the ToggleSwitch default template:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CUE">

<x:Double x:Key="ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness">0</x:Double>
<Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch" x:Key="GreenToggleSwitchStyle">
    .
    .
    .
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This code won't work, because of the Style 'GreenToggleSwitch' that I want to use.

How has the code to be like to work?

Basically I want to change the blue coloring around the toggle thumb(/knob) to green. If I put the code from my Resource file into my MainPage.xaml, it will work.

Appreciate your help,
Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, a resource dictionary isn't a style. What is the `x:Key` property of the style you want? Use that. If it's `x:Key="Planxty"`, use `Style="{StaticResource Planxty}"`. If it's `x:Key="ImALittleTeapot"`, use `Style="{StaticResource ImALittleTeapot}"`.

If it doesn't have a key, it's the implicit style and it should apply without any further effort on your part.

Secondly, you should merge the dictionary you're loading into the dictionary in your window/page/usercontrol/whatever.

Like so:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GreenToggleSwitch.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Page.Resources>
```

### Update

`GreenToggleSwitchResource` isn't defined anywhere. The XAML parser will not try to guess your intent when you throw weird random strings at it. It will say "Dammit, Jim, I'm a parser, not a parapsychologist!"

Use the identifier that you defined. This is programming. We call things by the identifiers we give them. You called it `GreenToggleSwitchStyle`. So that's how you refer to it.

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleSwitch"
    Style="{StaticResource GreenToggleSwitchStyle}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"
</ToggleSwitch>
```

I don't know what you're getting at with all the theme stuff and you didn't say, so I didn't address that.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this out.

Comment: I can't get that to work... I updated my provided information up in the question. Maybe you can figure out why it does not work.

Comment: @Viktor_DE What makes you think the parser can guess what "GreenToggleSwitchResource" is supposed to mean? You never defined it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was some stuff of my "try and error" moment... updated it.

Comment: Does that also work on UWP, isn't the <Window> part of Windows Forms?
Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: @Viktor_DE WPF not winforms. Make that Page.Resources